# pyfribidi for windows or any other bidi algorithm

Tags: python, arabic, reportlab, bidi

I'm trying to generate a report using reportlab, and the report language is Arabic. but the problem is reportlab doesn't support BIDI (Bidirection) Display because of the lack [BIDI Algorithm](http://unicode.org/reports/tr9/) support in Python. after alot of googling I found that there is a wrapper around Gnome [Fribidi](http://www.fribidi.org/) called [PyFribidi](http://pyfribidi.sourceforge.net/). but it compiled and runs only on Linux, I tried to build it on windows using mingwin but the compilation fails because a lot of linux libs not found.

My question is, is there any Unicode bi-direction algorithm implementation in python, that runs on windows?

thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Python BiDi](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-bidi/) is a great BiDi algorithm implementation, but it just support bi-direction (As Is) without fixing the [contextual form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_script_in_Unicode#Contextual_forms) of arabic script,  to solve contextual form problem, you should use python-bidi module with an arabic reshaper library called [python-arabic-reshaper](https://github.com/mpcabd/python-arabic-reshaper).

example : (from => http://mpcabd.igeex.biz/python-arabic-text-reshaper/)

```
import arabic_reshaper
from bidi.algorithm import get_display

#...
reshaped_text = arabic_reshaper.reshape(u'اللغة العربية رائعة')
bidi_text = get_display(reshaped_text)
pass_arabic_text_to_render(bidi_text)
#...
```

it fixes my problem perfectly, and both packages are pure python implementation.

Comment: Where can I find a java version of get_display?

Comment: Worked for me! Farsi Language! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In the meantime I implemented Arabic shaping in Python:

https://github.com/behdad/pyarabicshaping

Answer (score 1):

python-bidi http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-bidi/ is a pure python API so presumably it should work fine on windows.

You need to use the RL branch of reportlab and changes any calls to pyfribidi with calls to python-bidi. This link might help http://code.pediapress.com/wiki/wiki/RightToLeft

Comment: python-bidi is a great solution, I tried it before, it's perfect for hebrew, but arabic script needs special care about the char shape accourding to its position in the word. for optimum solution i found it after more than a year, please look at my answer=> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_script_in_Unicode#Contextual_forms

Comment: python-bidi only reverse the characters if needed. it won't do the job for Arabic or Persian languages. the actual problem is explained with pictures in [this link](https://github.com/mpcabd/python-arabic-reshaper)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another pure Python implementation of the Unicode bidi algorithm:
http://code.google.com/p/pybidi/