# Contents changed when generating Arabic report pdf

Tags: report, odoo, rml

I made an **rml** report in **openERP** version **6.0** with **Arabic** text, and I faced a little problem. When I generate **rml** from **SXW**, Arabic text was correct, but when I generate the PDF, the Arabic text is backward.

Comment: can u tell how it changes ? does it come it out backwards ?

Comment: ok vishal I am Putting string here so that you can got better Idea of problem. "أوافق على إجراء " this is the actual string but when report printed pdf it will "‫هاندأ عقوملا انأ‬" like this.

Comment: ya you are right Vishal it comes backward...

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167995/generate-a-pdf-that-automatically-prints

Comment: @Vishal Buddy I dont think so this question have any concern with above Question.

Answer (score 0):

Better you create a report in English and leave the translation job to the OpenERP translation engine.

Comment: I have arebic Static code i didnt got any English translation of it and can you please Explain what is OE and how can I use it in rml report in openERP

Comment: I think @firebug means to let OpenERP's translation engine do the translation work from English (edited the answer)

Answer (score 0):

this problems comes out because python doesn't have builtin [unicode bidirection](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr9/) algorithm. arabic text, like any other bidirectional language (Hebrew, Farsi, etc) must be reformatted through bidi-algorithm before exporting it into portable text rendering systems, like PDFs, Video Player subtitle rendering engines, 3D Design software....

There is a hook for openerp to fix this problem: http://github.com/barsi/openerp-rtl

it's built using thoughts from this thread: [pyfribidi for windows or any other bidi algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6137119/pyfribidi-for-windows-or-any-other-bidi-algorithm/)