# How to print right-to-left report on odoo 8

Tags: right-to-left, odoo-8, rml

I created a report in odoo 8 using RML, everything is good. but when i print the report, caracteres are printed from left to right. I tried with `drawRightString` but nothing does appears on the PDF.
I used `openerp-rtl` module but I noticed no changes.
What can i do to print it in RTL mode.

Answer (score 1):

Generally people working on Right to left text on Arbic Language.

so in this case you  just install the below python-bidi package :

## https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-bidi/

**python-bidi package** is helpful to set the Pure python implementation of the BiDi layout algorithm.

And also  add the bidi directory in your OpenERP report dir and use the `get_display(string)` method for making your sting convert into the arbic formate and also use with the `arabic_reshaper` class

You can do some thing like

```
import arabic_reshaper
from bidi.algorithm import get_display

def get_arabic_string(string):
    reshaped_text = arabic_reshaper.reshape(string)
    bidi_text = get_display(reshaped_text)
    return bidi_text
```

Just need to use the get_arbic_string function in your rml file  and set it on rml and pass the sting as arbic formate.

just check another source :

## [pyfribidi for windows or any other bidi algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6137119/pyfribidi-for-windows-or-any-other-bidi-algorithm)