# Print Arabic or any Right-to-Left writing-system string to Linux terminal using Python

Tags: python, linux, right-to-left

The very simple example is:

```
city = "‏المكلا‎"
print(city)
```

I am expecting the output to be:

```
‏المكلا‎
```

But in fact the ouput is the reverse string (the letters look a little different because they have a start-, middle- and end-form). I can't paste it here, because copy-pasting corrects the order of the string again.

How can I print Arabic correctly to the Linux terminal? The surounding text is left-to-right (LTR) and only this line needs to be right-to-left (RTL). Is there a UFT-8 character that can tell ther terminal that?

Comment: the terminal's going to assume you want LTR output (left-to-right). you need to configure it for RTL (right-to-left)

Comment: But I am only printing this string RTL. Everything else needs to stay LTR.

Comment: how is the terminal supposed to know that?

Comment: I was hoping that it work with inserting ```U+200F``` (unicode RTL-mark) at either end, but I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/q/983480.

Comment: Terminals do not work well with BiDi text.  Some terminals apply the BiDi algorithm, some don't. Some do Arabic letter shaping, some don't. You generally cannot know programmatically which one does what, you need to look. Your only hope is to find one that works, and stick with it (and tell your users which one to use).

Comment: BTW this is one of the very few good reasons to post a picture of text. Also please post which terminal you are using.

Comment: @MarcB Exactly the same way any other text processing program (like your browser for example) knows that. By running the Unicode BiDi algorithm.

Comment: FWIW, [konsole](https://imgur.com/a/DcR4XnW) works.

Answer (score 0):

To create a string with the RTL character:

```
rtl = u'\u200f'
```

Python 3 uses UTF strings by default, so in that case the "u" in front of the string would be unnecessary.

If the problem is actually that the terminal just can't render correctly, you could manually reverse the string.

```
test = 'Hello world'
test = test[::-1]
# test == 'dlroW olleH'
```

There is also the [python-bidi library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-bidi/) which might be able to help. ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3856403/right-to-left-languages-in-python))

Comment: Both of these solutions didn't work for me. Although reversing the order works for latin letters, they don't seem to do the same for Arabic. Confusing :)

Answer (score 0):

Some terminals do support printing Arabic.

For example, GNOME Terminal (in Ubuntu for example) works like this:

[image: Screenshot]

In this example, I typed `echo '`, followed by the letter `ع` than the letter `ل` than the letter `ى`, followed by `.'` and then I pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd>

As you can see, the word was displayed correctly on the screen, with the letters displayed from right to left, and joined, although the monospace font is showing a gap between the first letter and the second. This terminal did not however enable right-to-left mode for the whole line (in which case, the dot at the end would have been displayed all the way to the left). It also did not set the text alignment to the right for the line. The terminal `mlterm` does have these features, so you may want to try `mlterm`.

Comment: Hmm are you sure this looks right? My terminal displays something like `على.`

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Could you send a screenshot? The text in your comment looks similar to the screenshot to me.

Comment: Here https://imgur.com/a/btxP2Uz

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. The word على is displayed correctly in your screenshot. The line has not been set to right-to-left mode, though. If it did, the dot would appear on the left, not on the right. An Arabic speaker is writing from right to left, the word is written first, and then the dot, and so the dot is expected to be on the left, not the right. Or maybe you are talking about the spacing in my screenshot?

Comment: "The line has not been set to right-to-left mode" That's correct. The Unicode specs say the paragraph should be set to LTR or RTL according to the first directional character of the paragraph, but not all text processors do that.