# RTL (Arabic) misplace plus sing to the end of phone number in python

Tags: python, arabic, right-to-left, arabic-support

I have a Arabic SMS template with placeholder for customer support number, and replacing the placeholder with actual phone number (ex. +987654400). The plus sign (+) misplaced at end of number when replaced like 987654400+

Sample code:

```
>>> 
>>> s = '{customer_number} فتش'
>>> print s.replace('{customer_number}', '+987654400')
987654400+ فتش
>>> print '+987654400'.join(s.split('{customer_number}'))
987654400+ فتش

>>> 
>>> s = u'{customer_number} فتش'
>>> print s.replace('{customer_number}', '+987654400')
987654400+ فتش
>>> print '+987654400'.join(s.split('{customer_number}'))
987654400+ فتش
```

Python version 2.7.6, 2.7.10
OS: OSX 10.11.14
locale: English

--
It is not only happening in terminal, first I noticed this issue in API response which having following configuration.

Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS

python 2.7.6
django 1.7.6
django-tastypie 0.12.1

system locale : English
django project locale: English

Comment: what python version do you use? 2.7.3 works ok.

Comment: @Ricky python version 2.7.6

Comment: and what is your os and locale (arabic?)

Comment: Did you just changed your name?

Comment: @RickyA updated the question with requested information.  Yes just changed my name ;)

Comment: wow, that is weird. on ubuntu 12.04 py 2.7 I get the right thing: `+987654400 فتش ` but on osx py 2.7 I get: `+987654400 فتش`

Comment: it is even weirder because I copied the last one that showed `[arabic] [number]+` from the terminal but when I copied it here it got reverted back to what you see one comment above.

Comment: As I also can't reproduce the error you could try messing around with `"\u202E"` (right-to-left-override) or `"\u202D"` (left-to-right-override).

Comment: Looks like osx terminal is do magic. Can you try to print it in a file and see what it then looks like?

Comment: @RickyA I have exactly the same problem in Windows. But if you do `t = [s]
` and then `t[0].replace('{customer_number}', '+987654400')` you get `'+987654400 \xd9\x81\xd8\xaa\xd8\xb4'` so it is handled differently if it's in a list

Comment: Similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33700735/print-arabic-or-any-right-to-left-writing-system-string-to-linux-terminal-using

Comment: @roganjosh it handled differently because there is no arabic unicode chars at the beginning or end of the string (but `\xb4`), not because it is in a list...

Comment: @RickyA Not sure I understand, can you clarify? `s` is still the same string defined in the question (that contains the Arabic word), all I did was define a list called `t` that contains `s`. If I call `replace` on `s` I get identical output as in the original question (with the Arabic characters maintained but with the undesireable rearrangement) but if I do exactly the same with `t[0]` I get a different output with the correct arrangement.

Answer (score 2):

Somehow Osx `terminal` is doing magic with the string. If you print to a file it outputs the correct string.

python in terminal:

[image: Python 2.7 in osx terminal]

print to file:

[image]

file contents:

[image]

and the problem is really in the terminal because if we do this we see that the contents of the string are right:

[image]

And if we pad it with latin characters it is not doing funky rtl stuff:
[image]

Resume:
Osx and Windows terminals have rtl support that garbles your string. The contents of the string in python is ok, but is is mutilated by the os. Ubuntu does not have this problem since rtl support is not build in the terminal there.

Comment: It is not the problem only with terminal, actually it is wired in my API response which having following configuration python 2.7.6, django 1.7.6, django-tastypie 0.12.1

Comment: yey, hard to where things mess up then, but maybe you only have a problem at the end where things are displayed, and is the data correct in the db.

Comment: yes it is all correct in template, which maintained in file system as of now.

Comment: That is nice, then you only have a display problem :)

Comment: yes of course, but it display wired when return in response and also write in logs :(

Comment: well, the easiest solution would be to replace the `+` with `00` ;)

Comment: that is the last choice, but it will increase a char in SMS ;) Thanks for your time and ideas, Ricky.