# Why is the print order scrambled with a mix of floats and Arabic strings?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, printing

In Python 3, this:

```
alternates={'Qabr Ḩamdān', 'قبور حمدان', 'Qabr Hamdan', 'Qubur Hamdan', 'Qubūr Ḩamdān', 'qbwr hmdan'}
for x in alternates:
    print(12.1, x, 13.2)
```

produces this:

```
12.1 Qabr Ḩamdān 13.2
12.1 قبور حمدان 13.2
12.1 Qabr Hamdan 13.2
12.1 Qubur Hamdan 13.2
12.1 Qubūr Ḩamdān 13.2
12.1 qbwr hmdan 13.2
```

Notice the Arabic string in the second line is out of order. Why?

Comment: Perhaps because Arabic is right-to-left?

Comment: what version of python3 are you using? I just tested on Python 3.6.5 and it produces the expected output

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Right-to-Left and Left-to-Right printed nicely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42556063/python-right-to-left-and-left-to-right-printed-nicely)

Comment: @bunbun I've replicated the issue on 3.6.1: https://repl.it/repls/HonorableScentedDatamart

Comment: @pkpnd: The answer to the linked question might be how to fix or avoid the issue, but doesn't really explain **Why**, which is all the OP wants to know.

Comment: @martineau The answer to "Why" is given by my first comment.

Comment: IMO the answer to "Why" is because of the mixing of glyphs from RTL and LTR alphabets together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's normal. Arabic does that in Unicode.

Arabic is written right-to-left, and when an Arabic speaker types text, they're going to expect the Arabic to come out right-to-left... but they're going to expect numbers like `13.2` to come out as left-to-right chunks embedded within the overall right-to-left layout. The Unicode Bidirectional Algorithm does its best to meet this expectation. The details are *really complicated* and laid out in [Unicode Standard Annex #9](http://unicode.org/reports/tr9/).

Comment: Answers the question asked, so I'll upvote even though there's no mention of how to work around the problem (which one would assume the OP also would like to know even it they didn't explicitly ask for it).

Comment: If I understand correctly, the Bidirectional Algorithm is performed at the level of displaying the glyphs, ie. outside Python's control and is entirely up to the terminal/editor rendering the output. But if so, why would the Python version make a difference, as suggested in the comments to the OP? Is this a timing issue (string concatenation/flushing in different order inside `print`)?

Comment: ... or maybe bunbun and pkpnd see different results simply because their respective terminals implement the bidi algorithm differently?

Comment: @lenz: Probably a terminal thing, especially if one used a terminal and the other used a browser-based thing.