# Cannot use rtl and bold together in python-docx

Tags: python, python-docx

I try to create a Word document in Hebrew (aligned right and font set to `rtl`):

```py
p = document.add_paragraph()
run_format = p.paragraph_format
run_format.alignment = WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.RIGHT
runner = p.add_run(f.strip())
runner.bold = True
runner.font.rtl = True
```

However, `bold` is not applied to the text.

I tried to use `italic` instead and it is not applied as well. But, if I use `underline` it works.

Can someone explain this inconsistent behavior and how to solve it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42556063/right-to-left-and-left-to-right-printed-nicely After looking a while.