# Reversing Hebrew Characters

Tags: text

I'm not sure whether this is the correct site to be asking this, but here goes.

On [this](https://tablet.otzar.org/) site, there's a tool to export text from book pages by highlighting whichever paragraph/sentence you wish to export. However, whenever I do this, the Hebrew is inverted. Here is an example of what I mean:

[image]

So I've highlighted the text I want to be exported as text, but instead of the text coming out as:

`הגדרת מונחי יסוד`

It's instead come out backwards as:

`יסוד מונחי הגדרת`

---

To give an English example:

Instead of coming out as `He ran fast`,

it comes out as `fast ran He`

---

**So my question is, is there a tool (online possibly) that I can input the inverted text into to rectify the word order or do I need special software for this (if so, what software and how do I fix the issue with it)?**

Comment: I believe this is a RTL / LTR issue. If I understand correctly, there is a unicode character that defines sequence directionality that you need. The character may not be added in the tool.

Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3856403/right-to-left-languages-in-python can help you?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exacly sure what you are looking for but you can use this python script on an online python compiler where s is the text

```
    s = "יסוד מונחי הגדרת"
    s = s.split(" ")
    s_final = ""
    for i in range(len(s)):
        s_final += s[len(s) - i - 1] + " "
    print(s_final)

הגדרת מונחי יסוד
```