# Python/Tkinter writing from right to left (RTL) inside the text widget

Tags: python, tkinter, text-widget, tkinter-scrolledtext

-I am looking for a way to change the direction of writing from right to left in the text widget so that the user can write inside it in Arabic language, ie from right to left(RTL). I searched for this topic for several days, but unfortunately I did not find a real solution. Can you help me?
-In the event that there is no solution, how can I make the first line in the text widget undeletable (restricting the backspace in the first line), just because I was able to fix the writing direction (RTL) by inserting a word or a free space in the first line, but once it is deleted, the text widget retrieves the default setting (LTR).

Comment: maybe you should use ordinary text widget and if user tries to type something in Arabic (=in Arabic only) it automatically will be shown from right to left, won't it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3856403/right-to-left-languages-in-python

Comment: The default direction of writing in the ordinary text widget is (LTR), It does not display writing from right to left automatically.